# Superpositions of colored gratings

Tags: plotting

I created fork grating on mathematica and it is gray tone image, I need to conver it into Black and Blue image instead. And I use the Image code to do that but it didn't work! is there another way to do that?[image]

Comment: Use `Colorize[]` along with an appropriate `Blend[]` function.

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Than, can you please write an answer to your own question? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
w = w0 (1 + z^2/zR^2);
w1 = 100 200*^-6;
w0set = 2*^-6;
λ0 = 632*^-9;

Ixy2 = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[(.5 Exp[I (k x + Δϕ)] + .5 Exp[I l ArcTan[y, x]])*Conjugate[.5 Exp[I (k x + Δϕ)] + .5 Exp[I l ArcTan[y, x]]]]];
Grating0 = Ixy2 /. {k -> 11 2 π/λ 0/8, w0 -> w0set, zR -> π w0set^2/λ0, z -> 10*^-4, p -> 0, l -> 0, r -> Norm[{x, y}], Δϕ -> 0};
Grating1 = Ixy2 /. {k -> 11 2 π/λ 0/8, w0 -> w0set, zR -> π w0set^2/λ0, z -> 10*^-4, p -> 0, l -> 1, r -> Norm[{x, y}], Δϕ -> 0};

CFG = MatrixPlot[
  Table[
   Grating0 + Grating1,
   {y, -w1/1000, w1/1000, w1/500000},
   {x, -w1/1000, w1/1000, w1/500000}
   ],
  ColorFunction -> "GrayTones",
  Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 768
  ]
```

[image: BW]

```
Colorize[CFG, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Black}, #] &)]
```

[image: color]

Comment: Hey Alaa, thank you for taking the time to self-answer! Take a look at these guides to see how you can better format your code for readability: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951). Note also that you can always **edit** your own questions / answers by clicking on the "edit" link right underneath them.